# Column are missing in the result of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, header, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe like this:

```
         source_ip         dest_ip  dest_ip_usage  dest_ip_count
0    4:107:27:41   1:23:54:114        2028544              2
1    4:107:27:41   2:112:41:134        3145639              1
2    4:107:27:41   2:112:41:178        4145639              1
3  1:192:221:145  32:107:27:134        6358000              1
4  1:192:344:161   3:243:82:204        6341359              1
```

I am using syntax: `df1 = df.groupby(['source_ip','dest_ip'])['dest_ip_usage'].nlargest(2)`

But I am not getting indexes and getting result:

```
0    2028544
1    3145639
2    4145639
3    6358000
4    6341359
```

Comment: What you expect is unclear, also with the provided dataset no group has more than two elements, you won't do anything. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible when using `groupby` on multiple columns.

---

If you want to find `nlargest` with `groupby` on multiple columns you must use `apply` method on that specific column on which you are trying to find `nlargest`.

```
df.groupby(['source_ip'])['dest_ip','dest_ip_usage'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, columns=['dest_ip_usage']))
```